# a quality that must have vs a quality every person must have

Tags: relative-clauses

Are both sentences correct? I suppose that the first one is better (more common form). Is it true?

> Politeness is a quality that must have.
>
> Politeness is a quality every person must have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your first sentence is totally incorrect. This is because it is wanting in detail.

> Politeness is a quality that must have.

To see why this doesn't work we could temporarily dispense with the part *is a quality*: it doesn't affect the syntax, after all.

We then are left with

> Politeness must have

If it is still unclear to see why this abbreviated version doesn't work, you could further abbreviate the version and say

> Politeness has  (Imagine that *Politeness* "got" what it *must have had.*)

This version is ungrammatical because we're left with a *subject* and an incomplete *predicate.*

A helping verb like *has* above must take a main verb to complete the predicate.

By the same token, your second sentence is a perfectly grammatical sentence because it has a complete predicate.

To see why, you could turn around the word order and say instead

> Every person must have (the quality of) politeness.

Comment: So, I could say also "Politeness is a quality each must have.", isn't it?

Comment: @Sergey _each person_ :)